# Scrolling in GridViewPager on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I am currently designing a wearable app that uses a GridViewPager with 4 rows and 5 columns.

I have several questions regarding the scrolling:

1. Is it possible with a Java function to go directly to a specific line and column? I tried `scrollTo` but it isn't working.
2. Is it possible when changing line to always go in the second column or to stay in the same one instead of always coming back to the first one?
3. Or is it possible to go to another layout when swiping from left to right when on the first column instead of dismissing the app but with the ability to dismiss the app from this new activity?

Comment: I am facing the second issue. Did you find a way to keep grid on the same column while changing ? It always goes back to first column.

Answer (score 1):

For part 2 of your question, you can override `getCurrentColumnForRow(int row, int currentColumn)` in a custom GridPagerAdapter and set it to return `currentColumn`. That will allow it to stay in the same column when changing rows.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding part 1 of your question:

`scrollTo` is used to change a view's position on the screen.

You can call `GridViewPager.setCurrentItem(row,col)` instead.